# (Robot Framework IDE) RIDE->Search Tests Window-> Search tab what is "ADD all to Selected" used for

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

As the title says, in RIDE interface for Robot Framework, on the Search Tests Window, i have two Tabs:
1-Search   2- Add All to Selected
For first Tab, i wonder if i can insert a list of Test cases on search box and if the second TAB
will tick them on the interface.
I couldn't use it in this way but seems to function like that.
Any idea?

Edit:
So here i have added two complete test names separated with comma followed by space:
[image: Search Engine finds only the last test name]

but as you see the Search Engine finds only the last test name. I can search by what i have added as TestID inside Documentation of each test,and add something like :

TC-69, TC67   but search engine finds as before only the last test.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what version of RIDE you are using. In the past there was a bug on that search feature.
Today I have verified that Search function is working as expected on RIDE version 2.0b2, in Windows 10, Python 3.9 and wxPython 4.1.1.

I used a list in the Search box and then Add All to Selected. I use a large test name and a partial test name:

```
9__Checks if all the firewall rules related to the Network Discovery group are disabled, 2_
```

Here is a partial capture of the dialog (not the best colors combination ;) :
[image: Test Search in RIDE]

EDIT: Please edit the search text to not include the word `Acces` or `Accès`, so it is only `Contextuel_REFSITE`.

Another problem (could be a bug in RIDE) is the documentation having latin characters, and the search function become broken.

The tab Tag Search, will only search by tags, and then you have the option to add to Included or to Excluded tests.

Note: It is very important to confirm the version of RIDE you are using (Tools->View RIDE Log).

Comment: so i used Two complete test names (not partial) one followed by "Comma" then "Space" and then the second test name, but Search engine doesn't show both tests in the results.  Is the format of Comma+space correct?  and also how can i use a partial test name? I don't think i can use special characters like *

Comment: It could be the existence of latin chars that may cause the missing find. Can you, please add the names of the tests on your original question?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my search box

Comment: @Michelle Please add to the question the version of RIDE from Tools->View RIDE Log. Mine is: 20220927 19:33:57.263 [INFO]: Found Robot Framework version 5.0.1 from C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\robot.

20220927 19:33:57.264 [INFO]: Started RIDE v2.0b2 using python version 3.9.13 with wx version 4.1.1 in win32.

Comment: here are the information you requested:20221013 10:16:34.781 [INFO]: Found Robot Framework version 4.1.1 from C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\robot.

20221013 10:16:34.782 [INFO]: Started RIDE v2.0b1 using python version 3.9.0 with wx version 4.1.1 in win32.

Comment: @Michelle You can now upgrade both Robotframework and RIDE (`pip install -U --pre robotframework-ride` and `pip install -U robotframework`).